# Bash commands as variables failing when joining to form a single command

Tags: bash

```
ssh="ssh user@host"
dumpstructure="mysqldump --compress --default-character-set=utf8 --no-data --quick -u user -p database"
mysql=$ssh "$dumpstructure"
$mysql | gzip -c9 | cat > db_structure.sql.gz
```

This is failing on the third line with:

> mysqldump --compress --default-character-set=utf8 --no-data --quick -u user -p database: command not found

I've simplified my actualy script for the purpose of debugging this specific error. `$ssh` and `$dumpstructure` aren't always being joined together in the real script.

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chepner's answer is correct about the best way to do things like this, but the reason you're getting that error is actually even more basic. The line:

```
mysql=$ssh "$dumpstructure"
```

doesn't do anything like what you want. Because of the space between `$ssh` and `"$dumpstructure"`, it'll parse this as `environmentvar=value command`, which means it should execute the "mysqldump..." part with the environment variable `mysql` set to `ssh user@host`. But it's worse than that, since the double-quotes around `"$dumpstructure"` mean that it won't be split into words, and so the entire string gets treated as the command name (rather than `mysqldump` being the command name, and the rest being arguments to it).

If this had been the right way to go about building the command, the right way to stick the parts together would be:

```
mysql="$ssh $dumpstructure"
```

...so that the whole combined string gets treated as part of the value to assign to `mysql`. But as I said, you really should use Chepner's approach instead.

Answer (score 5):

Variables are meant to hold data, not commands. Use a function.

```
mysql () {
    ssh user@host mysqldump --compress --default-character-set=utf8 --nodata --quick -u user -p database
}

mysql | gzip -c9 > db_structure.sql.gz
```

*Arguments* to a command can be stored in an array.

```
# Although mysqldump is the name of a command, it is used here as an
# argument to ssh, indicating the command to run on a remote host
args=(mysqldump --compress --default-character-set=utf8 --nodata --quick -u user -p database)
ssh user@host "${args[@]}" | gzip -c9 > db_structure.sql.gz
```

Comment: As what you said, variable are meant to hold data, so tell me is command a kind of data? Yes, it's of course data. And what's more, OP's post is also supported, at least it worked fine on bash `4.2.46` with `x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu`. So the real problem is not because it's not a function. It's something else. And I do not think your answer is responsible for this question. Why would't we just help OP to figure out what was going wrong instead of gave a new solution?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, commands in variables should also work and can be in form of `$var` or just `$($var)`. If it says command not found, it could because the command maybe not in you `PATH`. Or you should give full path of you command.

**So let's put this vote down away and talk about this question.**

The real problem is `mysql=$ssh "$dumpstructure"`. This means you'll execute `$dumpstructure` with additional environment `mysql=$ssh`. So we got command not found exception. It's actually because `mysqldump` is located on remote server not this host, so it's reasonable this command is not found.

From this point, let's see how to fix this question.

OP want to dumpplicate mysql data from remote server, which means `$dumpstructure` shoud be executed remotely. Let's see third line `mysql=$ssh "$dumpstructure"`. Now we figure out this would result in problem. So what should be the correct command? The simplest command should be like `mysql="$ssh $dumpstructure"`, which means both `$ssh` and `$dumpstructure` will be join into single command line in variable `$mysql`.

At the end, let's talk about the last command line. I do not agree with `variable are meant to hold data, not command.` Cause command is also a kind of data. The real problem is how to use it correctly.

OP's command is also supported, at least it is supported on bash `4.2.46`.

So the real problem is how to use a variable to hold commands not import a new method to do that, wraping them into a bash function, for example.

So who can tell me why this answer does not come into readers' notice but be voted down?